# Multiple jquery functions doesn't work

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I have been trying the whole day to figure out why my code is not working. I have multiple functions in jQuery and when I try to combine them one of them won't work.

This is my whole code for now.

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        jQuery('#slider').anythingSlider({
            mode                : 'h',   // fade mode - new in v1.8!
            easing              : '<?php echo $data['slideshow_transition']; ?>',
            buildArrows         : <?php echo $data['slide_arrows']; ?>,      // If true, builds the forwards and backwards buttons 
            buildNavigation     : <?php echo $data['slide_anchor']; ?>,      // If true, builds a list of anchor links to link to each panel 
            buildStartStop      : <?php echo $data['slide_startstop']; ?>,      // If true, builds the start/stop button 
            toggleArrows        : <?php echo $data['slide_toggle_arrows']; ?>,     // If true, side navigation arrows will slide out on hovering & hide @ other times 
            toggleControls      : <?php echo $data['slide_toggle_controls']; ?>,     // if true, slide in controls (navigation + play/stop button) on hover and slide change, hide @ other times 
            startPanel          : <?php echo $data['slideshow_start_from']; ?>,
            autoPlay            : <?php echo $data['slideshow_pause']; ?>,     // If true, the slideshow will start running; replaces "startStopped" option 
            autoPlayLocked      : <?php echo $data['slideshow_user_pause']; ?>,     // If true, user changing slides will not stop the slideshow 
            autoPlayDelayed     : false,     // If true, starting a slideshow will delay advancing slides; if false, the slider will immediately advance to the next slide when slideshow starts 
            pauseOnHover        : <?php echo $data['slideshow_hover_pause']; ?>,      // If true & the slideshow is active, the slideshow will pause on hover 
            stopAtEnd           : <?php echo $data['slideshow_endstop']; ?>,     // If true & the slideshow is active, the slideshow will stop on the last page. This also stops the rewind effect when infiniteSlides is false. 
            playRtl             : <?php echo $data['slideshow_direction']; ?>,     // If true, the slideshow will move right-to-left 
            resumeOnVideoEnd    : true,      // If true & the slideshow is active & a supported video is playing, it will pause the autoplay until the video is complete 
            addWmodeToObject    : "opaque",
            onSlideBegin: function(e,slider) {
                // keep the current navigation tab in view
                slider.navWindow( slider.targetPage );
            }
        });
        // Videos on click grid and list style
        var animateSpeed = 500; 
        jQuery("#layout-controls a").click(function(){
            var curClass = jQuery('#videos').attr('class');
            var newClass = jQuery(this).attr('class');
            jQuery('#videos').fadeOut(animateSpeed,function(){
                jQuery('#videos').removeClass(curClass,animateSpeed);
                jQuery('#videos').addClass(newClass,animateSpeed);          
            }).fadeIn(animateSpeed);                        
            return false;       
        });
        jQuery("#cw-layout-controls a").click(function(){
            var curClass = jQuery('#cw-videos').attr('class');
            var newClass = jQuery(this).attr('class');
            jQuery('#cw-videos').fadeOut(animateSpeed,function(){
                jQuery('#cw-videos').removeClass(curClass,animateSpeed);
                jQuery('#cw-videos').addClass(newClass,animateSpeed);           
            }).fadeIn(animateSpeed);                        
            return false;       
        });
        //Validate contact form
        jQuery('#contactform').validate();
        //Slow scroll to comments area
        var commentTopPosition = jQuery('#comments').offset().top;
        // When #comment-scroll is clicked
        jQuery('#comment-scroll').click(function(){
            // Scroll down to 'commentTopPosition'
            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:commentTopPosition}, 'slow');
            // Stop the link from acting like a normal anchor link
            return false;
        });
        jQuery(".vf-table tr:even").addClass("even");
        jQuery(".vf-table tr td").css({'border-left': '1px solid <?php $borders ?>', 'border-right': '1px solid <?php $borders ?>'});
        jQuery(".vf-table tr th").css({'background': '<?php $borders ?>'});
    });
```

At start of code is anythingslider that i use on my newest theme, at the end of code is jquery code to add css style to my table in themes.

Code to change table style i was using before in different themes and in different js file. But in some reason it wont work in this one. When i make table borders to work anythingslider don't work, if i make anythingslider work other codes don't work.

I was trying to create .js file for every code separately and include it in theme, i was trying to include code from php file, i was trying to include code directly in header i was trying to add jquery no conflict i was trying $ instead of jQuery and none of it works. From this i don't see any errors in my code. Can someone smarter explain me what am i missing so my code is not working in this.

Comment: Is there a reason why your first bit of php code is in a string, and the others are not?

Comment: First part of code pull values from string from framework. Second part of code pull value from shortcode

Comment: Please give what the rendered code looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found where problem is.

On pages where comments are disabled there is no #comments div so here

```
var commentTopPosition = jQuery('#comments').offset().top;
```

jQuery breaks.

and everything after it breaks. I just made slight changes to my comments php file and now it works.

Comment: Mark this as an answer then so it makes life easier for others

Comment: I cant for another 2 days. When i click to mark it as answer it say i can accept my own answer after 2 days.